# show/hide (laravel) menus depending on roles

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have certain menu options visible only to certain users.

I've modified my user table in the standard auth framework by adding two roles - boolean columns: `isTeacher` and `isOnCommittee`.

I thought I'd try

1. create a method in my controller to check if the logged in user has the specific role, and then
2. in the view, call the method, and show the menu option, (or not).

It's all well and fine to put a `@if (Auth::iSTeacher())` into my view, but where do I put my function?

I did a search for `guest()` across all files and found this

```
...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard.php:
public function guest();

/**
 * Get the currently authenticated user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
```

I understand the purpose of a guard is protect a route, so this is not the place for it.

Where am I supposed to be creating my function?

(if you didn't guess - I'm very new to laravel.

Comment: i think you should use $_SESSION to check for the username.

Comment: You should put your function in your `UserController.php`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred way to do this would be with Authorization via the Gate Facade. You can define so-called "abilities" in AuthServiceProvider like this:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    });
}
```

Than inside views you can check:

```
@can('update-post', $post)
    <a href="/post/{{ $post->id }}/edit">Edit Post</a>
@endcan
```

Source:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#within-blade-templates

Comment: Thank you. Had to learn a few new things there, but that's what I'm here for ;) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) functions in your User model. e.g. write your `isTeacher()` in `User` model and in view check

```
@if(Auth::user()->isTeacher)
   YOUR CODE HERE
@end if
```

Comment: The principle of this makes sense. So in my user model I added a function   `public function scopeIsTeacher($query)
    {return true;}`     but I'm now getting errors `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Hmm.. as per documentation, 'Scopes should always return a query builder instance:' so, you may do your query in the scope and return result and in the view, you need to check teacher value.. guess its not an elegant solution. let me see If I can find anything.